# Fade bottom of UIWebView using CSS

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview, webkit, fade

I'm trying fade out the bottom of the UIWebView in my detailView. It's more like fading last 20-40 px. I'm using CSSTricks code for "ReadMoreFade" ([link](http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/)). My simplified version is pasted below.

My problem is when I start scrolling in my UIWebView, faded area stays there like a block. I'm attaching a screenshot that shows this. Any suggestions or hints? Thank you.

SCREENSHOT:
http://i51.tinypic.com/2rmxsfp.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Fade bottom</title>
 <style>
  body{background:#FFF}
  p {
   color:#000;
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:justify;
   text-indent:30px;
   width:600px;
  }

  #fadeBottom {
   background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, rgba(255,255,255,0)),color-stop(1, rgba(255,255,255,0.7)));
   bottom:0;
   height:50px;
   left:0;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Some long text here. Lorem ipsum?</p>
 <div id="fadeBottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, I'd just make a white image with a transparent gradient and overlay it on top of that UIWebView as needed. It's going to be a lot quicker than trying to debug browser stuff...

Comment: I thought of that but wanted to know if I can do it with just CSS3 using gradients. It works great on Safari just not in iPhone.

Comment: Yeah, who knows. I'm not very good at web development, but I wouldn't be surprised if apple turned off that kind of repeated rendering on the iPhone. It also might cause problems when you pinch to zoom in, though I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use an image or a CSS3 gradient, I'm afraid [`position:fixed` doesn't work on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009577-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5).

Comment: You are right. "CSS fixed positioning works in Safari on iPhone and iPad, but not as you might expect." I'm looking into this code at this moment and seems to be working well in Mobile Safari: http://doctyper.com/stuff/iphone/fixed/. Thank you.