# HTML and UIWebView div positioning at the bottom

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview, css-position

I used the following code to place a div  at the bottom:

```
<div style = "position:fixed; bottom:2px; left:2px;">
```

and also this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;bottom:10px;">
```

this does put it on the bottom, but there is a problem if the text above it is too long. If the text is long, it goes beyond the webview so you would have the scroll down to see the rest. But the div I want to place at the bottom isn't completely at the bottom; it stays at the bottom if I weren't to scroll down, which means that it goes over the text.

Basically, I want the div to be at the bottom, but if the content is bigger than what the webview allows, the div positioned will appear OVER the content, and NOT at the absolute bottom.

Comment: if u don't mind. what is the exact the Q?

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry about that; ask me for more clarity if needed

Comment: Are u using loadHtmlString to load the webview content ?

Comment: then you can append this html div tag at the bottom, I mean at the end of the string. That should do the trick ! I have done it once and it came successfully.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question; that was what I did. The div does stay at the bottom, but only when the webview doesn't require any scrolling to view the content further. If the content is long and goes beyond the webview, then the div appears OVER the content, instead of it being at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that link (http://cubiq.org/iscroll)
OR
Try this from stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796097/fade-bottom-of-uiwebview-using-css)

Comment: the stackoverflow question is exactly what I'm asking too, but it isn't answered yet.

I'll try out the iScroll method and report back, thank you.